# how to display custom 404 only for *.html?

Tags: nginx

There is a line

```
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

in my nginx config

But I need to display custom 404 page only for *.html files? Not for CSS, JS, etc.

I've tried

```
   location ~ \.html {
      error_page 404 /404.html;
   }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a html project ?

Comment: Didn't you try it in .htaccess ?

Comment: @TechGuy please close this tab